# Отсутствие реакции на подставной запрос

Tags: php, mysql

Сразу скажу... в PHP я никогда не работал, столкнулся только сейчас по учебным целям. Работаю на JS и осваиваю C++. Осталась только одна загвоздка в последней лабораторной работе, над которой я пыхтел почти 4 дня... пробовал 3 метода решения, ничего не сработало... сейчас решил написать и выложить здесь самую упрощенную версию:

```
$query="
    (
    SELECT 
    `pilots`.`fio`
    FROM `pilots`
    WHERE `pilots`.`fio` LIKE ?
    )";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);

$pilot_fio='%';

if(isset($_GET['pilot_fio']) && $_GET['pilot_fio']!='')
{
$pilot_fio='%'.$_GET['pilot_fio'].'%';
}

$stmt->bind_param("s", $pilot_fio);
$stmt->execute();
$result=$stmt->get_result();
$result=$mysqli->query($query);
var_dump($query);print('{----------}');
```

Суть в том, что данный запрос не выводит ничего, абсолютно... ни ошибки... ни варнинга... ни результата... ничего... в JS подстановка устроена полегче...

Я должен сравнить введенное имя извне с тем, что есть в БД, однако ответом мне служит только пустота... если я буду пробовать методы в виде подстановки строки в запрос, все будет работать, и по сути если убрать LIKE ? и вернуть обычный механизм, то все будет пахать.. однако по заданию, требуется реализовать данный способ...

Вывод запроса: string(116) " ( SELECT `pilots`.`pilot_id`, `pilots`.`fio` FROM `pilots` WHERE `pilots`.`fio` LIKE ? )" {----------}

P.S: Все имена таблиц и столбцов правильны и использованы в моих предыдущих работах.

Comment: "сейчас решил написать на форум" - на какой форум? Вы публикуете в настоящий момент ваш вопрос на данном ресурсе.

Comment: Добавьте к вопросу значение `$pilot_fio` перед mysql запросом.

Comment: Сделайте `var_dump` результата запроса, а не самого запроса. И уберите `$result=$mysqli->query($query);`

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt = new mysqli(.......);  // надеюсь, не забыли подключиться к базе данных

if(isset($_GET['pilot_fio'])) {

    $query = " SELECT * FROM pilots WHERE fio LIKE ?";

    $pilot_fio = "%{$_GET['pilot_fio']}%";

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);

    $stmt->bind_param("s", $pilot_fio);

    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    if($stmt->affected_rows) {

        echo "совпадение найдено";     

    }

}else {

    echo "pilot_fio не определено, запрос не может быть выполнен";      

}

$stmt->close();
```

Comment: В ответ ниже добавил результат... не коректный...

Comment: не корректный - какой конкретнее?

Comment: Ниже подробно все описал, нет вывода... возможно нет просто подстановки переменной $pilot_fio в запрос... я специально сделал ее отдельный вывод, чтобы проверить, создается ли она вообще...
P.S: код вставил в отдельный ответ, ибо в комментариии это не лезет...

Answer (score 0):

Есть таблица `pilots`, в которой существует поле `fio`, которое необходимо вывести и по которому необходимо фильтровать.
На странице есть поле ввода `fio`.
Подключение есть заранее и находится в stmt. Закрывается также в нужное время.
При попытке ввода в него значения "Петков", выдает следующее:
Input: %Петков% ---------------NON ROWS! ERROR! -------------- string(74) " `SELECT pilots.fio AS fio FROM pilots WHERE fio LIKE ?" {----------}`

Из чего делаю вывод, что поле он читает однако не "засовывает" в запрос значение.

Внизу представлен ваш интерапритированый код, однако он немного не подходит, ибо нужно также выводить строки без фильтра. поэтому я решил добавить код после else без фильтрации.
Однако и в этом случае получаем:
NON FILTER ----------------string(74) " SELECT `pilots`.`fio` AS `fio` FROM `pilots` WHERE `fio`" {----------}

if($stmt->affected_rows) - тут уже эта строка не дает результата...

Что делать? Вот уже тот же эффект несколько дней...

```
if(isset($_GET['fio']) && $_GET['fio']!='') {
echo "WITH FILTER -----------------";
$query = " 
SELECT 
`pilots`.`fio` AS `fio`
FROM `pilots`
WHERE `fio` LIKE ?";

$pilot_fio = "%{$_GET['fio']}%";

echo "Input: {$pilot_fio} ---------------";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);

$stmt->bind_param("s", $pilot_fio);

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();

if($stmt->affected_rows) {
    echo "NON ROWS! ERROR! -------------- ";     
} 
} else {
echo "NON FILTER ----------------";
$query = " 
SELECT `pilots`.`fio` AS `fio` 
FROM `pilots`
WHERE `fio`";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

if($stmt->affected_rows) {
    echo "NON ROWS! ERROR! -------------- ";     
}
}

var_dump($query);print('{----------}');
```